# What are the differences between `evaluate`, `rwhnf` and `seq` and their "deep" counterparts?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In [the wiki page about timing computations](https://wiki.haskell.org/Timing_computations), there is an example for timing a pure computation. The core idea is to use the functions `evaluate`, `rnf` and `seq` to ensure that the desired computation (`1 + y` in the example below) is performed between the two calls to `getCPUTime`:

```
time :: (Num t, NFData t) => t -> IO ()
time y = do
    start <- getCPUTime
    replicateM_ lim $ do
        x <- evaluate $ 1 + y
        rnf x `seq` return ()
    end   <- getCPUTime
```

I would like to clarify the use of the functions `evaluate`, `rnf` and `seq` here.

First, `evaluate` evaluates its argument to weak head normal form, but it seems that its other purpose is to deal with exceptions that may happen during evaluation. I'm not exactly sure what would happen without it, but I'm ready to assume that it's needed for exception handling.

Then, `rnf` evaluates the value to normal form to make sure that the whole computation happens here and that no unevaluated bits remain in weak head normal form, as a result of the call to `evaluate`. This may or may not be what one wants, as discussed [here](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/tutorial.html#benchmarking-pure-functions), because the additional evaluation may not be necessary.

Finaly, `seq` makes sure that the expression `rnf x` is evaluated to weak head normal form before returning `return ()`.

To summarize: `evaluate` deals with potential exceptions, `rnf` evaluates `x` deeply to make sure that the whole computation is timed and `seq` ensures that `rnf x` is evaluated in time.

Here are my questions:

1. Isn't the call to `seq` redundant with the call to `rnf` which has already evaluated the value to normal form?
2. If I'd prefer to time the evaluation to weak head normal form rather than to normal form, may I simply replace `rnf` with `rwhnf`? Then would the 3 calls `evaluate`, `rwhnf` and `seq` be redundant such that I could eliminate the use of the last 2 and be happy with just `evaluate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The call to `seq` is not redundant because `rnf x` needs to be evaluated (to WHNF) to evaluate `x` to NF, and that's `seq`'s job.
2. Yes, I believe so: just

   ```
   evaluate $ 1 + y
   return ()
   ```

But! If the intention of `evaluate` here is to handle exceptions I don't think it works because they can be thrown from `rnf x` just as well. And if it isn't, I don't see the benefit over

```
rnf (1 + y) `seq` return ()
```

And both [`force`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.4.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:force) and `evaluate` docs suggest a simpler alternative:

```
evaluate $ force $ 1 + y
return ()
```

Maybe that page was written before `force` was available? Even so, unless I am missing something,

```
evaluate $ rnf $ 1 + y
```

would do the job correctly.

Comment: So using either `evaluate $ 1 + y` or `evaluate $ force $ 1 + y` is sufficient to ensure that the computation is done up to respectively weak head normal form or normal form. Can we completely abandon the calls to `rnf` and `seq`?

Comment: I believe so (of course, `force` uses `rnf` inside).